# Understanding Angularjs from the perspectieve of other frameworks like backbone or openui5

Tags: jquery, angularjs, backbone.js, architecture

This question might have been asked a million times but unfortunately I am not able to find answers and hence request your help.
I am coming from other frameworks like backbone, backbone-marionette and openui5 and now trying to learn angularjs as it seems to be more flexible and feature rich than other frameworks besides the vast community behind it. But I am not able to get few concepts right at all, no matter how many tutorials I go through or how man courses I read. Please have a look at below image. I will ask my questions in comparison to other frameworks and how I would have done it in other frameworks and may be angular gurus can help me understand how it is done in angular
[image]

1. Generally you have 3 parts in any web page - header, body and footer. In backbone or Openui5 you can control each html element (example  or ) as a view and have its own controller. And hence in backbone or openui5 I would use headerView to capture the login details and when the user logs in change the headerView and BodyView to reflect loggedin user. But in backbone I understand you can have only one ng-view
2. When a user logs In then in backbone I can emit a global event which can be listened by any views and then change the contents of view and behavior of controller accordingly.
3. Advantage of this way of structuring is that I can leave the header part as it is throughout user interaction with the web page and change only the body part because header view and controller are clearly separated. In agnular I understand that you can have only one view - does this mean I have to repeat the header template and behavior of of header controller and body template and body controller in every template that I create for user interaction?
4. Also in backbone and openui5 I can manage global data for example for loggedin user, but this I understand that I can do by using factory module of angular, is this correct or is there a better way?
5. In openui5 and backbone, I can pass data from one view/controller to another, how can I do this in angular. For example in openui5 I would have done as below.

   var controller1 = getbyId('view1').getController(),
       controller2 = getbyId('view2').getController();
   controller2.user2 = controller1.user1;
6. In openui5 when route changes, I can instantiate a new view place it in whichever container/element I want, and also I have complete control on each input field and each button etc.. To give an example, when user1 logs In I will replace Menu3 by Menu4 and when when user2 logs In I will replace menu3 by menu5. How can I hook on to each element in angular should I use jquery to replace the element by using #id of each element or can I do it in a better way?

**

> Finally, I will be really happy if someone can guide me to a tutorial
>   which contains end to end building of app with login.

**
Many thanks to everyone for helping me out.

Regards,
Chidan

Answer (score 2):

Please see the below diagram for architectural understanding:
[image]

Here i have used header and footer as ng-include templates as most of the login based applications have entirely different layout for login screen and then have same header and footer throught the app after login. In this way you have capability to create dynamic templates and use as many different layouts.

**Answers Regarding your Points:** 
1.
In the header.html file declare inline controller e.g. `<header data-ng-controller="HeaderController as header">` so you can manage header part of your page seperately from your body part and it will be centralized as well. Same goes for the footer part.

2.
Angular also support events so you can emit events to identify when user is logged in or out you can listen these events in any controller to change the template behavior accordingly.

3.
Using ng-include within ng-view will definately load with every route change but you have centralized location to manage changes throughout the website.

4.
Yes this is a correct way. You can also use html5 localstorage for this purpose if the data is not sensitive. The disadvantage of html5 localstorage is security it can be hacked through injecting malicious javascript.

5.
You can use services and rootscope events to share the data between controllers.

6.
Better approach to create your user specific elements from json based data so you only need to manage their attributes and changes will be reflect on view.

**Notes:** 
a. Using alias with controller names helps you determine which controller you are referring inside view e.g. header.title will always be looked into HeaderController not in the controller you specified on routeConfig. 
b. If your footer part remains static throghout the website take it out from ng-view. 
c. Your index.html or bootstrap file contain only stylesheets , external javascripts and static html.

Comment: Thanks Shayan, in your reply using alias you mean using "Controller As" right? And do you know of any tutorial which wold cover angular from architectural point of view, because all the tutorials I have come across are for beginners and not really for some one who is coming from other frameworks

Comment: One more question - to use angular animation where I want to get sliding animation, should I change the whole view?

Comment: Yes alias means using "Controller As".
angular animations is quite simple to use basically angular adds class on events like show hide enter and leave and you can apply css transitions on those classes.